# how can we configure null removable components(object field) of a class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, components

suppose we have a class with some components(object fields) that some of them can be null(removed)
Is it suitable to create a new class without the (component) field or use interface to handle it. suppose we have several components that can be removed for some objects
Thx in advance

```
public class Class1{
   Component1 component1;
   Component2 component2;
   Component3 component3;//can be null (removed)
   Component4 component4;//can be null (removed)
}
public class Class2{//removed component3,component4(new class)
   Component1 component1;
   Component2 component2;      
}
public class Class3{//removed component3(new class)
   Component1 component1;
   Component2 component2;  
   Component4 component4;  
}
public class Class4{//removed component4(new class)
   Component1 component1;
   Component2 component2;      
   Component3 component3;      
}
```

or use interface

```
public interface IComponent1{

}
public class Component1:IComponent1{

}
public class NoComponent1:IComponent1{

}
public interface IComponent2{

}
public class Component2:IComponent2{

}
public class NoComponent2:IComponent2{

}
public interface IComponent3{

}
public class Component3:IComponent3{

}
public class NoComponent3:IComponent3{

}
public interface IComponent4{

}
public class Component4:IComponent4{

}
public class NoComponent4:IComponent4{

}
public class Class1{
    IComponent1 componentBehaviour1;
    IComponent2 componentBehaviour2;
    IComponent3 componentBehaviour3;
    IComponent4 componentBehaviour4;
}
```

or check null condition(if needed) in methods of the class.

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion based and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. That said, my opinion is that if the fields are _always_ unused for a particular set of objects, then yes...it could very well be appropriate to separate the class into separate classes, with fields appropriate to the instances of each of those separate classes. If, on the other hand, there is a scenario where you would have to replace one instance of one class with an instance of some other class just because you had a `null` value at first and no longer do, or vice a versa, then no...don't do that.

Comment: Thank you but If I have several classes with some same fields how can I access to the object field of different classes (for example in loop). Shoud I implemet GetComponent() for theses classes with generic?

Comment: _"I have several classes with some same fields"_ -- why would you do that? If they are the same fields, make them the same class. If for some reason they can't be the same class, then consider defining an interface that each of those classes can implement, then you can just use the interface when you need those fields.

Comment: I said some! it is components that can be or not. Component based design pattern

Comment: suppose we have a class that has Displayable field (Displayable displayable ) and one class does not have. I want to implement component based class not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience it is better to follow object oriented principles. In you case I think you should create a class first for all mandatory fields:

```
    public class Class1{
   Component1 component1; 
   Component2 component2;
   }
```

Then using interfaces for each nullable fields, like:

```
 public Interface interface1{
       Component1 component3; 
       }
```

and then another interface like:

```
public Interface interface2{
           Component1 component4; 
           }
```

Then in you class you could have:

```
public class Class2: Class1, interface1
```

and also another classes like:

```
    public class Class2: Class1, interface2
    public class Class3: Class1, interface1, interface2
```

Comment: component field into interface?!
you can only have interface methods and getter setter into an interface

Comment: You can have interface of Component in interface, something like `IComponent`

Answer (score 0):

May sound silly, but why don't you just have one single class exposing a collection of Components? 
Something like this:

```
public interface IComponent{}

public class Foo{
    private readonly IList<IComponent> _components;

    public void AddComponent(IComponent component){
        // do your magic here
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetComponents<T>() where T : IComponent {
        // do your magic here
    }
}
```